# Adaptive Toasts with Actions on Windows 10 can be sent through WNS?

Tags: toast, wns

Windows 10 came with actions in toast notifications, like you can see in [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-adaptive-interactive-toasts). But in the schema reference of them does not show "actions" as child elements.

This notifications can be sent as push notifications through WNS or they can just be sent as local notifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notification payload is just passed through by WNS, so any notification that can be popped locally can also be pushed.

Comment: I will test it. If it works. I will mark as an awswer. Thanks.